# HTTP allowed method not working in apache2

Tags: linux, apache-2.4

I have allowed HTTP method but still, it is not working, please help me.

```
<Directory />
    AllowMethods GET PUT POST HEAD OPTIONS TRACE
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: don't specify that on Directory / . It is the root directory of the filesystem! Bad setup. It works unless you override it in another directory.

Comment: Do I need to add another directory?

Answer (score 0):

In your Apache Virtual Host, add the OPTIONS in

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

You would also need to set the appropriate header in order to make a successful request. For JWT Token, you can send it through the Authorization header.

```
this.$http.get(this.$apiUrl + `rest/api/public/User/user/` + payload.id_user, {
    // if i remove this headers, request works OK 
    headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token 
    } 
})
```

you can also refer to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547027/apache-server-method-not-allowed-when-requesting-from-http-localhost8080) for more information.

Comment: Followed that, but getting an error while restarting the apache server.

Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
                                                                            
I have edited virtual host file and added "Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS""

Comment: Try changing the directory `cd /etc/apache2` , then `apache2ctl configtest` .This makes you to trace any errors in apache config file.you can have a look into this [case](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629995/apache-not-able-to-restart) for more findings.@ArunKumar